# Duplicate Title Tags Webmaster Tools - URL 1: Has No Date, URL 2: Has Date Appended

Tags: tags, duplicates, title, google-search-console

So just going through GOogle Webmaster to clean out some 404's and check overall site health, and I've only just discovered about 200 posts that have been flagged as having Duplicate Title Tags.

So here's one common example. Post seems to have two versions, one with out the date format and one with. There isn't two versions of the post in the database, so it's just the one post but I guess has been indexed twice. I do believe I played with changing Permalink format a while back, to remove the date, so pretty sure this would be the few posts that slipped through.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2kono8jba0m6m0/Screenshot%202014-03-10%2014.41.53.jpg

**Alternative NFL Team Logo Designs by Justin Halpern**

*/alternative-nfl-team-logo-designs-by-justin-halpern/2012/02/02*

*/alternative-nfl-team-logo-designs-by-justin-halpern*

Wondering the easiest way to simply ignore/fix/noindex/redirect the 'non date' version (last line) for all these few 100 posts.

To clarify my permalink structure is:

imjustcreative.com/example-post/2012/02/02

I did think I could use Yoasts Canonical Link feature in each 'edit post' and set the canonical link appropriately, but not sure if that's possible as each post is viewable in it's own formate, ie I can view each of the post versions without any automatic URL structure change.

So kind, :)
Graham